# How to unistall play framework from mac lion OS?

Tags: java, playframework

I removed the play 2.0 file which was extracted to my /Applications. But, When I type 'play' in the terminal. Everything works like normal ??

Any other solid ways to get play off my system?

Comment: is it still being referred to in the path?  do you have another play directory that is being pointed to?

Comment: what do you get if run: 'which play' ?

Comment: ls -la /usr/local/bin/play to check if it's a symlink - otherwise just rm /usr/local/bin/play